# Why does plotting $\frac{3n+1}{2^k}$ give several apparently straight lines?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, graphing-functions, prime-factorization, collatz-conjecture

Here's the plot for $f(n)=\frac{3n+1}{2^k}$ ($n$ integer, positive, odd) where $k$ is the number of 2 factors in $3n+1$:

[image]

Just to be clear, here's a zoom in:

[image]

Why do we see those straight lines? I assume it should be something trivial, but I fail to prove this.

---

**Edit #1** Here's how $k(n)$ looks like:

[image]

Comment: The top line consists of those points where $3n+1$ is odd. The next line of those points where $3n+1$ is even but not divisible by four. The next line forms when $3n+1$ is divisible by four but not divisible by eight. And so forth, just like PackSciences explained.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f_k (n) = \frac{3}{2^k} n + \frac{1}{2^k} = a_k n + b_k $ which is a linear function.

Comment: The function itself is not linear because $k$ depends on $n$ (to some degree that I can't yet explain). Moreover we can see in the graph that $f_k(n)$ is actually made of several distinct lines so it's not linear for sure (unless I miss something).

Comment: Each line represent a value of $k$, which is why you notice all those lines. I know that $k$ is a function of $n$, but your analysis was graphical, and you can just split the cases depending on the value of $k$.

Comment: This explains why each of those lines is a linear function - it makes sense. But why do $a_k$ and $b_k$ give those lines? The subtle difference between your answer and what I'm trying to figure out is why $k$ varies like it does as $n$ grows (see **Edit #1**).

Comment: @Razvan Well my answer is an answer to "Why do we see those straight lines?" not why $k$ varies like that as $n$ grows because those two problems are unrelated since the "straight lines" are just same values of $k$s. You plotted the density and it's more probable to get lower values of $k$ because of the factors of $3n+1$

Comment: It's clear now, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume for the following $j \in \mathbb N$

First look at each number taken by $\small n = 4j+3$ giving $\small 3(4j+3)+1 = 12j+10 =2^1 (6j+5) $
Second look at each number taken by $\small n = 8j+1$ giving $\small 3(8j+1)+1 = 24j+4 =2^2 (6j+1) $
Third look at each number taken by $\small n = 16j+13$ giving $\small 3(16j+13)+1 = 48j+40 =2^3 (6j+5) $
Fourth look at each number taken by $\small n = 32j+5$ giving $\small 3(32j+5)+1 = 96j+16 =2^4 (6j+1) $
and so on...

Now look at the list of the results with a fixed $k$, for instance $k=4$, which occurs in the exponent of $2^k$ in the last entries. Then we have the curve $x=n = 32j+5 \to 2^4(6j+1) \to y=6j+1 $ or $x=32j+5, y=6j+1$ and then 
$$ 16y-3x=1 $$
and then, as expected,
$$  y = f_4(x) = {3x+1 \over 16}  $$
which is a linear function with slope roughly $y'(x) \approx 1/5$.
Now by your own introductional function-definition you have, that for that type of numbers $x(j)=2^4 \cdot 2 j+5 \to y(j)=6j+1$ only odd integers for $x$ and $y$ may occur so you have a discrete graph, thus dots, but lying on a linear pattern.

For each $k$ you have one dotted "line" in the same way, which we "see" (actually interpolate...) in your pictures.  Four our example $k=4$, this is the fourth dotted line and for instance at $x=5000$ it is $y=15001/16 \approx  937.5$ which is near $y=1000$ (with small error) which we can immediately see in the first picture.

Last step is to prove, that the introducing table covers all odd integers. But I think that's easy enough for you?

Comment: Yes, that seems to naturally cover all the odd numbers. Thanks for explaining this.